# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when trying to run an x86-64 APK on an x86-64 AVD in QtCreator

Tags: android, x86-64, qt-creator, android-virtual-device

I don't want to plug in my phone each time I try to run a compiled APK  and also ARM emulation is quite slow in x86 systems.So I decided to add a kit in the QtCreator IDE merely to build APKs for x86 to be able to run them easily in the AVD.

[image]

There's no error or warning related to the kit configuration in the IDE but when I build the project to run it on my x86-64 AVD , I get this:

```
adb: failed to install whatever.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
Installing to device failed!
```

By the way I'm sure I'm using the correct AVD in the `Select Android Device` window and I've installed the `x86_64` components for Qt via the **Maintenance Tool**.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself.Here's the instructions:

1. Go to **Projects** mode:

[image]

2.Under the `Build Steps` section select the desired **ABI**(For Qt 5.14 when you install `Android` tools via the **MaintainerTool** program,libraries for all of these ABIs would be installed automatically):

[image]

Hope it helps the future readers to save some time.